# обновление промежуточных результатов через TextView при длительных вычислениях

Tags: android, android-studio, многопоточность, textview

при длительных вычислениях требуется вывести промежуточные результаты , сейчас делаю так:

```
String INFO="";
    public void info(String s) {
        INFO=s;
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                iTV.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        iTV.setText(INFO);
                    }
                });
            }
        }).start();
    }
```

но TextView не обновляется. И показывает только когда все вычисления окончены. Что я не правильно делаю?

Comment: Вы длительные вычисления видимо в UI потоке делаете? Вот он и блокируется, пока не вычислит. А в коде вообще не видно никаких вычислений.

Comment: В Android таких целей подходит класс `AsyncTask`, который позволяет выводить промежуточные данные в ui-потоке.

Comment: вычисления идут в основном потоке, но разве создавая новый поток я не могу обновлять интерфейс?

Comment: Android не позволит вам обновить интерфейс не из основного потока (`CalledFromWrongThreadException`). Весь UI работает только в нём.

Answer (score 0):

спасибо за советы, помогло запустить длительные вычисления в отдельном потоке.

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
public void run() {
    createLifeMatrix();
}
}).start();
```